# FastAPI understanding Get path paramenters

Tags: fastapi

very new to coding and have been going through a FastAPI online video course. Learning about the CRUD operators and get operation. In the lesson I understand the first basic about get:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

STUDENTS = {
    'student_1': {'fullname': 'Tom Hanks', 'address': 'Hollywood', 'dob': 'July 27', 'citizenship': '1234'},
    'student_2': {'fullname': 'Ozzy Osbourne', 'address': 'London', 'dob': 'January 23', 'citizenship': '2345'},
    'student_3': {'fullname': 'Tom Brady', 'address': 'Tampa Bay', 'dob': 'October 17', 'citizenship': '23233'},
    'student_4': {'fullname': 'Andre Agassi', 'address': 'New York', 'dob': 'September 11', 'citizenship': '34545'},
    'student_5': {'fullname': 'Al Capone', 'address': 'Chicago', 'dob': 'January 12', 'citizenship': '9283'},
}

@app.get("/")
async def read_all_students():
    return STUDENTS
```

I understand this returns all the listed student details.

There is another get operation that I am struggling to understand:

```
@app.get("/{student_id}")
async def read_student(student_id: str):
    return STUDENTS[student_id]
```

In this code, swagger UI asks for the student ID which per the above code is "student_#". How does this identity that as the correct value? WE have not assigned student_# as the student_id? My question basically is what is the logic that when we put this code as student_id, it knows its the field "student_#"  in the above code?

Comment: check out this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cejAYrz47qo . It has a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To break down the statements and try to let you make sense of it.

The first statement tells FastAPI that you want to have an endpoint located under `/<give_a_student_id_here>`, and that this endpoint can be requested with an GET operation:

```
@app.get("/{student_id}")
```

The `{student_id}` part is the *name* that will capture whatever is given after `/` - this can be `student_id` (since it's a student id that is given, this is a good name that describes what the value represents), but it could have been anything - for example just `foo`:

```
@app.get("/{foo}")
```

.. it has no connection to the format used in the data structure (`student_#`); it's just formatted a similarly in this specific code.

However, the function that the `@app.get` call decorates *has to use the same name for an argument*, so that FastAPI knows which variable to fill out with the value from the URL:

```
@app.get("/{student_id}")   <- student_id from the path 
async def read_student(student_id: str): <- gets inserted into the same variable here
```

After that, the value that has been captured inside the `student_id` variable is used to look up the student in your dictionary and return that value:

```
return STUDENTS[student_id]
```

So if you request `/student_4`, `student_id` will have the value `student_4` inside it, and uses that as a key into the dictionary.

If you instead used the name `foo` for the path in the request URL, it would look like this (maybe this helps show that the variable being named `student_id` and the key in the dictionary being `student_#` isn't connected in any way):

```
@app.get("/{foo}")
async def read_student(foo: str):
    return STUDENTS[foo]
```

The variable `foo` will now contain the value `student_4` which is used as a key into the STUDENTS dictionary, and then resolves to this value:

```
'student_4': {'fullname': 'Andre Agassi', 'address': 'New York', 'dob': 'September 11', 'citizenship': '34545'},
```

.. which gets returned from the endpoint.